# How do window jambs secure to the framing when foam insulation fills the gap of air between them?

Tags: windows, replacement, window-frame

It is my *understanding* that a window's jambs attach to the framing (header, footer and studs surrounding the window pocket, and which are part of the house's framing).

It is my *understanding* that a window's sashes then attach to the jambs.

If either of those are incorrect, please begin by correcting me! But assuming I'm more or less correct there...

---

It appears that typically a layer of spray foam insulation is applied in between the framing and the jambs. If thats the case, it means there is a pocket of airspace in between framing and the jambs. If thats the case, how and where do the jambs secure themselves to the framing...they can't just be floating in mid-air or depending on the foam insulation to provide the fastening, right?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long nails/screws.

Usually use shims for spacing/sizing and drive the nail though jamb, shim and into framing.

The foam is just to fill the open space to block air movement.

Comment: Thanks @crip659 (+1) -- crazy question here: if my window sashes are the _exact_ perfect size to be installed into the framing without _any_ jambs, is there anything wrong with installing the "window" (sashing) without jambs, directly to the framing? Meaning, say the inside vertical dimension of the framing (from header to footer) is 50", and the inside horizontal dimension of the framing (from left stud to right study) is 30". And let's say I just happen to have a window with sashing this is 50"x30"...could I just install it directly to the framing, and leave the jambs out of it?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup  You can.  You want to check on how the drywall/wall finish will match.  You also want some open space between the window and frame to allow for slight movement, probably about a 1/4 inch.  Windows do not like being squeezed.

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup if your window actual size _exactly_ matches the rough opening, then you're counting on the rough opening being perfectly square. If it's not perfectly square, it'll force the window slightly out of shape and the window won't open/close properly. This is why rough openings are 1/2 - 1" bigger than the door/window they're designed to house - to allow the _rough_ framing to be rough while the inserted item can still operate properly by being shimmed exactly square.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably more than one way to do it but what I've seen is some wood shims are used to place the window correctly and it is then screwed into place  from the jambs all the way to the framing.

You want it square so it operates correctly. And then plumb/level so it looks good. Also make sure it's aligned with the wall (eg. not protruding more one side).

Double check everything after the screws are in. Then you fill any remaining gap with foam or whatever else you want to use as insulation.

Comment: If you use foam, make sure to use low-expanding foam designed for windows, or else the foam will cause the windows to bow and warp.  Or you could pack fiberglass insulation into the openings as well for a similar result, though the foam will probably end up slightly less drafty since it seals better than fiberglass.